# How to cryptanalyze the message using permution cipher

Tags: permutation

The message is:
ACAUI MMGRC AILEE HKREG EAISW OSTHDS

With a grid size of 6 x 6. The forbidden cells are in different rows and different columns, so there are no two forbidden cells in the same line.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Because "I have tried to solve it" is not the same as showing sufficient effort, which is what we require for questions that look like an assignment or test. Writing down some of your thought processes would do it.